# Variable no need to be declared in lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda

```
vector<int> v(10);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [i=0]() mutable { return i++; });
```

Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: For that specific case I would suggest [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead.

Comment: As for your question, please see e.g. [this lambda expression reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for details.

Comment: But you *are* declaring it. See, it's right here `[i=0]` ;)

Comment: Can you explain, why it shouldn't? In other words, what you expected?